# Nctoolkit repeated select on same data

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am looking at monthly precipitation data over Africa and would like to break the data into sub-regions. Is there a way to do multiple selections/crops on the same ds?
Here is my code:

```
fn1 = 'cru_monthly_africa.nc'
ds1 = nt.open_data(fn1)
#Selecting a specific variable, time period and area and then calculating the field mean for each month:
ds1.select(variables = "pre")
ds1.select(years = range(1981, 2018))
ds1.crop(lon = [20, 27], lat = [-35, -33.5])
ds1.spatial_mean()
ds1.tmean("month")
#Export to xarray
ds1csc_xr = ds1.to_xarray()

#Next region:
ds1.select(variables = "pre")
ds1.select(years = range(1981, 2018))
ds1.crop(lon = [17, 20], lat = [-35, -31])
ds1.spatial_mean()
ds1.tmean("month")
#Export to xarray
ds1swc_xr = ds1.to_xarray()
```

I would now like to do the exact same but using a different set of lat and lon coordinates and write it to a separate xarray (i.e. each sub-region to be its own xarray). If I try repeat the code in my script but change the coordinates and name of the output xr, it just gives me the same values as the first xr.
I am new to using python and nctoolkit for netcdf files with climate data and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: It is not clear why what you have done failed. Can you add the full code? Repeating it and modifying the coordinates should work

Comment: @RobertWilson I added the code for the next region, but the output (ds1swc_xr) has the same data as the previous output (ds1csc_xr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to modify your code so that you are copying the ds1 dataset before cropping it. Right now you are cropping ds1 twice.

```
fn1 = 'cru_monthly_africa.nc'
ds1 = nt.open_data(fn1)
#Selecting a specific variable, time period and area and then calculating 
#the field mean for each month:
ds1.select(variables = "pre")
ds1.select(years = range(1981, 2018))
ds2 = ds1.copy()
ds1.crop(lon = [20, 27], lat = [-35, -33.5])
ds1.spatial_mean()
ds1.tmean("month")
#Export to xarray
ds1csc_xr = ds1.to_xarray()

#Next region:
ds2.crop(lon = [17, 20], lat = [-35, -31])
ds2.spatial_mean()
ds2.tmean("month")
#Export to xarray
ds2swc_xr = ds2.to_xarray()
```

Alternatively, you could just replace the second cropping with:

```
#Next region:
ds1 = nt.open_data(fn1)
ds1.select(variables = "pre")
ds1.select(years = range(1981, 2018))
ds1.crop(lon = [17, 20], lat = [-35, -31])
ds1.spatial_mean()
ds1.tmean("month")
#Export to xarray
ds1swc_xr = ds1.to_xarray()
```

There is likely not much difference in terms of computation time.